# Is any morphism from an affine scheme to arbitrary scheme is separated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

It seems to me that $X \rightarrow Y$ with $X$ affine is separated. Since we have the composition $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ is a morphism between affine schemes hence separated. But I never ever see anyone talking about this simple result. The common one is a morphism between affine schemes is separated.

Comment: Yes, this is just an instance of the fact that if $X\to Y\to Z$ is separated, then $X\to Y$ is separated ([Stacks 01KV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KV), for instance). I don't understand the rest of the complaint here - there are entire areas of algebraic geometry that never have to seriously worry about separatedness, for instance, so certainly they would never need to discuss this result.

Comment: As an aside to KReiser's excellent comment, the following Stacks tag is the result you mention with your exact proof, so it seems that some people do talk about this result: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KN